# Is there an accepted Java equivalent to Python's zip()?

Tags: java, collections

I've got two `List` objects and I want to pair them up, just like the [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function in Python. I'm pretty sure this isn't available in the JDK, but is there something like this in a fairly widespread library, similar to [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/)? Thanks.

Comment: Not well versed in Python and how zip is used but a Quick glance makes me thing that ListUtils from the Collections library should do the trick.
combinedList = ListUtils.union(list1, list2) ; 
Iterate over the combined list.
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html#union(java.util.List,%20java.util.List)

Comment: @trappski, that's just a wrapper for List.addAll which does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Functional Java](http://FunctionalJava.Org/) has [`zip`](http://www.functionaljava.org/javadoc/4.6/functionaljava/fj/data/List.html#zipWith--), `zipWith` and `zipIndex` the way you would expect from Haskell or Scala. (Indeed, the authors are pretty much all Haskell programmers.)

Comment: Actually, the version I linked to is the first-class version. (I couldn't figure out how to link to the other version without Markdown gobbling up the link.) IOW: it's not the `zipWith` *function* it's a function that *returns* the `zipWith` function. The signature for the *real* `zipWith` is `public <B,C> List<C> zipWith(List<B> bs, F2<A,B,C> f)`, which is basically the same as the Haskell one: `(a → b → c) → [a] → [b] → [c]`. It takes a list of as (the implicit `this`), a list of bs and a function from a and b to c and returns a list of cs.