# How to iterate over two Collections of Objects simultaneously?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to most elegantly iterate through parallel collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365793/how-to-most-elegantly-iterate-through-parallel-collections)
>   [Is there an accepted Java equivalent to Python's zip()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118932/is-there-an-accepted-java-equivalent-to-pythons-zip)

I have to iterate simultaneously over two Collections of objects to see if their members are equal. Is there a way of using a counter to access the object or do something similar to the for loop below ?

```
Boolean compareCollection(Collection<Object> c1, Collection<Object> c2)
{
     //something like -
     for (Object ob1 : c1, Object ob2 : c2){
           //check if ob1.val == ob2.val
     }
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public static boolean compareCollection(Collection<Object> c1, Collection<Object> c2)   {
    if (c1 == null)
        return c2 == null;
    else if (c2 == null || c1.size() != c2.size())
        return false;
    Iterator<Object> it1 = c1.iterator();
    Iterator<Object> it2 = c2.iterator();
    while (it1.hasNext()) {
        Object o1 = it1.next();
        Object o2 = it2.next();
        if (!o1.equals(o2))
            return false;
    }
     return true;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to parameterize the collections with the right type (which I'm guessing is not just `Object`) and making the appropriate comparison:

```
if (!o1.val.equals(o2.val))
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you just use `List.equals()`,  which implements similar logic?

Also, commons-collections `ListUtils.isListEquals` may be what you want:
http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html

Comment: `CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection(Collection a, Collection b)` is a better choice for ... collections.

Comment: Every `Collection` is not a `List`.

Comment: fair point - CollectionUtils is probably better, although the logic above comparing elements in order is more list-like.