# Sorting two parallel arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, one stores the distance of the cities and the other stores the corresponding population. Everything works fine if the distance of the cities is in ascending order.
But let say if someone inputs the distance randomly. How can I sort the cities array and also make sure that the population of the respective city is in the same index as the index of its respective city population.

For example:

- City 1 has population 333
- City 3 has population 33333
- City 5 has population 33

```java
int[] city = {1, 3, 5};
int[] pop  = {333, 33333, 33};
```

Everything works fine because the city array is sorted already.

But when I input:

```java
int[] city = {3, 1, 5};
int[] pop  = {3333, 333, 33};
```

Big problem!

I want sort the array city and make sure that the population array has all its elements at the same index as their respective city.

Comment: As they are related information, maybe it is a good idea to store both information on a City Object.

Answer (score 9):

The good way of doing this is having a city class:

```
class City{
    private int id;
    private long population;

    //... getters, setters, etc
}
```

a city comparator class:

```
class CityPopulationComparator implements Comparator<City> {
    @Override
    public int compare(City c1, City c2) {
        return Long.compare(c1.getPopulation(), c2.getPopulation());
    }
}
```

And an array list of cities:

```
ArrayList<City> cities;
```

and finally sort it using:

```
Collections.sort(cities, new CityPopulationComparator());
```

**But** if you need to have your cities and populations this way, you can write a sort method yourself (a bubble sort for example) and whenever you swap two cities, also swap corresponding pupulations.

Comment: The `City` class can even implement `Comparable<City>` as an alternative. This way, you can call `Collections.sort` with only the collection of `cities`.

Comment: Also, when dealing with sorting and collections, your object should override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods as well. This will make each object truly unique.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Yes. and since I thought it isn't the "natural" ordering of City, I preferred the `Comparator` way.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl There will be many ways of sorting cities. I'm not sure sorting by population is more natural than sorting by id. That makes using a Comparator for the specific sort a good plan. I would have called it CityPopulationComparator.

Comment: @AliSeyedi: Does the order of `id`s matter if the population of two cities is equivalent?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It depends on his requirement. I just provided this as an example.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36440636/3973077). However if you want a completely mad hack, you can do this:

```
public final class ParallelIntArrays extends AbstractList<int[]> {

    private final int[] array1;
    private final int[] array2;

    public ParallelIntArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        if (array1.length != array2.length)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.array1 = array1;
        this.array2 = array2;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] get(int i) {
        return new int[] { array1[i], array2[i] };
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] set(int i, int[] a) {
        if (a.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        int[] b = get(i);
        array1[i] = a[0];
        array2[i] = a[1];
        return b;
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
int[] city = {5,   1,  2,    4,   3   };
int[] pop =  {100, 30, 4000, 400, 5000};
new ParallelIntArrays(city, pop).sort(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[0]));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(city));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pop));
```

Note that as written above, `ParallelIntArrays` does not function correctly as a `List`. For example `list.contains(list.get(0))` would give `false`. If you made it a `List<IntBuffer>` or a `List<List<Integer>>` instead, it would be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If your city id is unique:

```java
int[] city = { 3,    1,   5};
int[] pop  = {3333, 333, 33};
Map<Integer, Integer> arr = new HashMap<>(city.length);
for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
    arr.put(city[i], pop[i]);
}
Arrays.sort(city);
for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
    pop[i] = arr.get(city[i]);
}
```

The same using [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

```java
int[] city = { 3,    1,   5};
int[] pop  = {3333, 333, 33};
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> arr = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < city.length; i++) {
    arr.put(city[i], pop[i]);
}
System.out.println(arr.keySet());
System.out.println(arr.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

A "cheap" way would be to have a third array which would contain 0 to n representing the index of the other arrays

But the problem you are having would disappear if they were grouped in a class, both information seem logically related.
Then you would implement Comparable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18896422

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] bidAmount = {3000, 54000, 2000, 1000, 5600};
    String[] bidderName = {"Jenny", "Mike", "Alvin", "Berry", "John"};
    Map<Integer, String> stringTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
    stringTreeMap.put(bidAmount[0], bidderName[0]);
    stringTreeMap.put(bidAmount[1], bidderName[1]);
    stringTreeMap.put(bidAmount[2], bidderName[2]);
    stringTreeMap.put(bidAmount[3], bidderName[3]);
    stringTreeMap.put(bidAmount[4], bidderName[4]);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : stringTreeMap.entrySet()) {
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + " => " + value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect a third array containing pairs of elements of these two arrays and sort it. Then you can iterate over this array and replace the elements of the first two arrays:

```java
int[] city = {3, 1, 5};
int[] pop = {333, 33333, 33};

int[][] sorted = IntStream.range(0, city.length)
        // Stream<int[]>
        .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{city[i], pop[i]})
        // sort by city
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(arr -> arr[0]))
        .toArray(int[][]::new);

// replace the elements of the first two arrays
IntStream.range(0, sorted.length).forEach(i -> {
    city[i] = sorted[i][0];
    pop[i] = sorted[i][1];
});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(city)); // [1, 3, 5]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pop)); // [33333, 333, 33]
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do I sort two arrays in relation to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65985628/14940971)</sup>