# How do I sort two arrays relative to each other?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to make a Student Grade Program where there are 2 arrays: `String[]` Student and `double[]` Grade.
I cloned them to have a sorted array and an unsorted one.

Arrays:

```java
public class Testcode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ArrN[] = {"Garcia", "Magsilang", "Magbag"};
        double ArrG[] = {2.5, 1.25, 1.5};

        String ArrN2[] = ArrN.clone();
        double ArrG2[] = ArrG.clone();

        Arrays.sort(ArrN2);
        Arrays.sort(ArrG2);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrN1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrN2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrG2));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ArrG2));
    }
}
```

Now, how do I make an output that looks like the one below (Grade Sorted)

```
- 1.25               Magsilang
- 1.5                Magbag
- 2.5                Garcia
```

or (Student Sorted)

```
- Garcia             2.5
- Magbag             1.5
- Magsilang          1.25
```

Comment: Why not create a `StudentGrade` class to put both names and grade at one place

Comment: I've actually created a class to house the arrays but my question is like this let's say 
Array1 = "SA","SB",SC" //StudentName
Array2 = 1.0,3.0,5.0       //Student Grade

Output should be Grade Sorted as the Highest while showing the Corresponding Name on the same index of the array

1.0 = SA
3.0 = SC
5.0 = SB

Comment: Maintaining order between two separate arrays will be really annoying. Your best option is to create a dedicated class to store both things (name and grade of a single student) and have an array of those objects. Then you can get it sorted by name or by grade, however you want, and always get the other related data.

Comment: Then creating a studentgrade.class then inheriting it to the main.class would solve the problem? If that is so then is there a code where I could base upon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not dealing individually with only names and grades. I would suggest creating a `StudentGrade` class for your problem like this:

```java
private static class StudentGrade {
    String name;
    double grade;

    public StudentGrade(String n, double g) {
        this.name = n;
        this.grade = g;
    }
}
```

You can create an array of `StudentGrade[]` and sort it with whatever field which fits your use case. I sorted it with `name` and `grade` and I was able to see expected output;

```java
StudentGrade[] studentGrades = new StudentGrade[] {
        new StudentGrade("Garcia", 2.5),
        new StudentGrade("Magsilang", 1.25),
        new StudentGrade("Magbag", 1.5)
};

// Sort By Name
System.out.println("(Student Sorted):");
Arrays.sort(studentGrades, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.name));
printStudentGrades(studentGrades);

// Sort by Grade
System.out.println("(Grade Sorted):");
Arrays.sort(studentGrades, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.grade));
printStudentGrades(studentGrades);
```

This prints this output:

```
(Student Sorted):
Garcia 2.5
Magbag 1.5
Magsilang 1.25
(Grade Sorted):
Magsilang 1.25
Magbag 1.5
Garcia 2.5
```

Comment: OK, thank for this I would definitely try this to my code and experiment with it.

Comment: okay, please let me know if it's working for your use case or not whenever you try it.

Comment: OK, I will update you then after I can confirm it worked in my switch-case statement thanks again

Comment: It worked on the switch-case arguments but with a little tweaking. Overall the program works.

Answer (score 2):

As other said, it makes more sense if you have a separated class `StudentGrade`, which holds name and grade, and then you take advantage from already implemented algorithm `Collections.sort`, which from Java 8 accepts method reference of your class.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class StudentGrade {

    private String name;
    private double grade;

    public StudentGrade(String name, double grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(double grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}

public class Testcode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<StudentGrade> students = new ArrayList<>();

        students.add(new StudentGrade("Garcia", 2.5));
        students.add(new StudentGrade("Magsilang", 1.5));
        students.add(new StudentGrade("Magbag", 1.25));

        Collections.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(StudentGrade::getGrade));
        System.out.println("Grade Sorted");
        for (StudentGrade studentGrade : students) {
            System.out.println(studentGrade.getGrade() + " " + studentGrade.getName());
        }

        Collections.sort(students, Comparator.comparing(StudentGrade::getName));
        System.out.println("\nStudent Sorted");
        for (StudentGrade studentGrade : students) {
            System.out.println(studentGrade.getName() + " " + studentGrade.getGrade());
        }

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Grade Sorted
1.25 Magbag
1.5 Magsilang
2.5 Garcia

Student Sorted
Garcia 2.5
Magbag 1.25
Magsilang 1.5
```

Comment: OK, thank for this I would definitely try this to my code and experiment with it

Comment: You're welcome. Would you mind voting up and accept the answer? That would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to get your 2nd output. Used [`Bubble sort`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/bubble_sort_algorithm.htm) to sort the array!

```java
class TestCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ArrN[] = {"Garcia", "Magsilang", "Magbag"};
        double ArrG[] = {2.5, 1.25, 1.5};

        //bubble sort based on ArrG array
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrG.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ArrG.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (ArrG[j] < ArrG[j + 1]) {
                    double temp = ArrG[j];
                    ArrG[j] = ArrG[j + 1];
                    ArrG[j + 1] = temp;

                    String tempN = ArrN[j];
                    ArrN[j] = ArrN[j + 1];
                    ArrN[j + 1] = tempN;
                }
            }
        }

        // print the array
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrG.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(ArrN[i] + " " + ArrG[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Garcia 2.5
Magbag 1.5
Magsilang 1.25
```

This is a basic approach! You can also use a `Class` or built-in `Array()` methods!

Answer (score 0):

To get a *sorted copy* of two arrays with respect to each other you can first *link in pairs* the elements of these arrays, and then sort these *pairs* - you get a sorted list. As a container for each pair you can use [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-), or an array, or some *class*. For example:

```java
String[] arrN = {"Garcia", "Magsilang", "Magbag"};
double[] arrG = {2.5, 1.25, 1.5};
```

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Double>> list = IntStream
        // assuming the two arrays are the same length,
        // iterate over the indices of the first array
        .range(0, arrN.length)
        // link a pair of two elements
        .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(arrN[i], arrG[i]))
        // collect a list of map entries
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```java
// sort by name
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());
list.forEach(System.out::println);
//Garcia=2.5
//Magbag=1.5
//Magsilang=1.25
```

```java
// sort by grades
list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
list.forEach(System.out::println);
//Magsilang=1.25
//Magbag=1.5
//Garcia=2.5
```

---

<sup>See also: [How do I relate one array input to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165491/14940971)</sup>